# How to use button position in XCtest?

Tags: objective-c, xctest

I have few dynamic buttons in my app which has no labels, how can I use position of button to tap it ? or co-ordinates is also fine with me,I have tried using `[app.cells.buttons.allElementsBoundByIndex[0] tap];` and it dint help me

Comment: If you set a breakpoint there, are you certain that `app.cells` is not nil and valid?  How about `app.cells.buttons`?  You could also try looping through the cells and for each cell, see if you can get the buttons array.

Comment: I had tried looping and also `app.cells.buttons` it dint help me :(